# How do we react to (possible) sock puppets?

Tags: discussion, users

User [Henry](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/478/) has asked about the possible role of Tot Lins(d)ell in establishing the Wagga Bush Fire Brigade.

User [Adam](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/198/) has asked (separately) about Henry Flood and education in Darlington Point.

Some background reading reveals that in 1868-69, ownership of the Darlington Pub transferred from Linsell to Flood.

- Does this indicate the GFH:SE has had a breakthrough in uniting two
  independent researchers with a common connection? That would
  be wonderful.
- Or could it be that a pair of researchers acquainted IRL have decided
  to join GFH:SE together to extend the range of sources and expertise
  available to them? That would be terrific.
- Or might this indicate that the Adam and Henry are not in fact two
  users but the same person? That might be cause for concern.

Comment: Note, even if these two *were* sock puppets, having a sock puppet in itself is not a crime. *Voting abuse* is the crime. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65604/192187 for reference.

Comment: Sock puppet and IRL - Google search found them thanks. A sockpuppet is an online identity used for purposes of deception. IRL means in real life. Now the question makes some sense.

Comment: My first thought on seeing this post was as the site was new and there was a fair degree of invites sent during commitment that the 2 may be referrals from such invites. Whether they know each other or are common persons to a third is possible.

Answer (score 8):

> Or could it be that a pair of researchers acquainted IRL have decided to join GFH:SE together to extend the range of sources and expertise available to them? That would be terrific.

At this point, with the site being this young, that is probably a fair conclusion.

The moderators do keep their eyes open for socks and other forms of abuse, and if you *strongly* suspect a problem you should contact them (via a flag)... But otherwise, assume that folks finding this site and finding it useful will bring their friends and colleagues along.

And that's a *good* thing!

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to assume innocent until proven guilty. The way se extends is people making connections with q/a they care about. We need more people with common interests and should not worry they might be sock puppets. I'm sure the geekier se sites have had a lot of abuse and se is going to be better at catching sock puppets than we are. [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13770/how-can-i-make-it-more-difficult-for-a-user-to-create-multiple-accounts/13775#13775) on [security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/) has the kind of things that can be done - and I believe se does some of them.

Note the only real abuse I think a sock puppet could do are:

- make our stats look better (more users, more activity)
- voting abuse (which you'd need more than 2 to really make a difference)

The first would be a shame (more likely to get site killed than help) and the second has happened enough that se appears to have controls in place. Even when they aren't sock puppets, se as ways to keep voting cliques from forming (since cliques abuse a true community).

Answer (score 1):

Although it's possible (if less than ideal) for people to have multiple accounts here, if those accounts start interacting with each other (by voting for each other, by answering each other's questions, or commenting on each other's questions or answers), that isn't allowed.

Comment: "multiple accounts here" - different accounts on different se sites is how se works. But it does encourage linking them - and hopefully the bonus rep for linking them would outweigh the benefits of voting for yourself. If by "here" you mean on genealogy, then I would think we would prefer only one account per person. Is there any advantage to the community for one person having two genealogy persona's? Is there any advantage to the individual (other than for abuse)?

Comment: Can you include the reference to 'it is perfectly acceptable for one individual to have 2 accounts on Genealogy.SE'? It's generally not a good security policy where voting is involved for one individual to have multiple voting persona's.

Comment: Based on http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/should-one-person-have-multiple-genealogy-se-accounts/1592#1592, I believe 'there's no problem with people having multiple accounts' is incorrect.

Comment: @Duncan, My answer is consistent with http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/should-one-person-have-multiple-genealogy-se-accounts/1592#1592, other than Robert's expressed *preference* that people don't have multiple accounts. I've modified the wording slightly, although it was originally copied from http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607/195988 on the assumption that http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood would know what he was talking about...